# intent not available across applications

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

I'm seeing a very strange behavior whereby when I have two separate apps and I side load them (or run them both from Eclipse) and launch one with the other, providing some data in the Intent, the receiving app gets the info.

However, when the apks for these two apps are installed via a browser download (not from the Play store, just downloaded from an internet address, and installed) the Intent on the receiving app comes across as empty.

I'm wondering if I'm overlooking some permission or restriction, and if not, what I can do to get around this problem. I'm LITERALLY not changing anything other than the method of installation and seeing this side-effect, so, I'm pretty sure that this isn't a red herring of some sort.  Have tested across a multitude of devices.

The two apps have different package names and aren't related in any way (other than having the same encryption key, though I don't believe that has anything at all to do with the price of tea in China).

Comment: Are you overriding `onNewIntent()` in the receiving activity? If not, do so, and see if it is getting called. If it is, your `Intent` extra is probably in *that* `Intent` (parameter to `onNewIntent()`), not the one from `getIntent()`. If `onNewIntent()` is not being called... I'd recommend editing your question and explaining the exact sequence of steps that you are performing, on a fresh emulator instance (or device with your apps uninstalled), that is giving you these symptoms.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the response.  I'll do as you ask, but the bugger of it is that when the apps are not installed from the web (side loaded from machine, or run directly from eclipse... in both cases ON the device) the Intent comes along in the onCreate/onResume.  Have you ever seen a situation where the manner of installation (namely, installing from the web) would produce such a problem? As I said, that's quite literally the only difference between this working perfectly and not working at all.

Comment: "Have you ever seen a situation where the manner of installation (namely, installing from the web) would produce such a problem?" -- well, I'm guessing that there are other differences that happen to be a side effect of how you are doing the installs. In this case, if the receiving activity is already running, and there's nothing causing the new `startActivity()` call to create a second instance in a new task, Android may be just bringing the existing instance to the foreground, and therefore calling `onNewIntent()` on it.

Comment: I'm starting to chalk this up to witches.  I swear to you, there are no other differences and I've tested and tested and tested. When side loaded from local, I can run these apps (and have) 30 times in a row with every permutation of pausing/resuming whatever. Works perfectly.  Loaded from the web, and it fails 100%. I'm going to try your solution... It doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but then, nothing about this does.

Comment: "I'm starting to chalk this up to witches" -- I do not recommend throwing your test devices into the pond to see if they float. :)

Comment: OOH... I solved it! Adding answer now

Comment: Oh, and by the time you made your comment, I had already thrown 3 of them into the pool.  They didn't float.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that I was totally missing a (seemingly) important mechanism for data transfer between `Activities`, which is documented here:
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

and here

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

The sending Activity needs to add the data (in my case Stringfied JSON as)

```
//...whatever other Intent setup you need
it.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, jsonObj.toString());
it.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(it);
```

And the receiving `Acitivity` amongst other things that you'll see in the documentation above needs to specify in the Manifest that it's willing to accept such values with this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

I hadn't seen this documentation and was passing the data in the totally generic way (just packing Extras into the Intent).  The larger question, I guess, is why my generic way worked at all, if there's such a specific way that it's *supposed to work.  Obviously my fault for not reading all the documentation and playing along, but it I'm really curious what distinction Android makes between apps that are side loaded via USB, vs. apps that are side loaded from the internet.

Anyway... live and learn.

Comment: You are confusing a specific scenario and a general case. For two *independent* apps, for *`ACTION_SEND`*, the convention is to use the MIME type to indicate the type of data in the `EXTRA_TEXT` extra. That way, sender and receiver both know what's going on. But it's just a convention for `ACTION_SEND` (e.g., the MIME type for `ACTION_VIEW` refers to the type of the data pointed to by the `Uri`). And "passing the data in the totally generic way (just packing Extras into the Intent)" is perfectly legitimate, when you are the implementer of both sides of the communications.

Comment: "I'm really curious what distinction Android makes between apps that are side loaded via USB, vs. apps that are side loaded from the internet" -- publish a pair of projects that implements a reproducible scenario, and I'll take a peek at it. BTW, did you happen to try my `onNewIntent()` suggestion?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I never got a chance to as my solution resolved the issue.  In hindsight I agree 100% with your previous comment. I have apps deployed right now that do exactly this (collect Intent information without any `ACTION_SEND` specific additives. I'll need to pull the previous version from GIT and compiling it. I'll get it to you soon.